# Problems with Wordpress on Rackspace Cloud Server

Tags: ftp, wordpress, cloud, rackspace

I have a rackspace cloud server running Ubuntu 12. I've setup the web server, PHP and MySQL and it's all working with my custom PHPs and databases performing as expected

But, the problem arises when I install wordpress. The installation was smooth but I can't add any plugins or media from the dashboard

When I try to add the plugins, it asks me for my FTP details. I've setup the server entirely in SSH via terminal. I have not used any FTP related thing in it. So I'm clueless about it

Next, when I try to add media, it says it does not have enough permissions even though I've granted full permissions to the database user. Besides, I cannot change the wp-content folder to 777 from security point of view.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the owner of wp-content to be the same as whatever user Apache is running as - it might be "apache" or "nobody". You're having this issue because WordPress cannot update itself unless Apache has permission to change the contents of the wp-content directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access to the server, just upload your plugins to the plugins folder.

http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2007/02/11/how-to-install-configure-and-use-wordpress-plugins/

The images thing is pretty common, I've run into it myself before. I am sure you'll find an answer in their support:

http://wordpress.org/search/error+uploading+images?forums=1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and wound up adding this line to wp-config.php to fix it:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

I also had to recursively change ownership for a directory and it's files to wp-data as mentioned above and all was well.

```
chown -R www-data wp-content
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As Nada stated you need to change the owner of that directory to www-data which should be the user apache is running as.